# how to define a two dimensional array using domain models library in ruby?

Tags: ruby, domain-model

In order to define a field with one dimension which contains Integers,  used to define in the below format using domain models library.

```
class Sample
 include DomainModel

 field :numbers, :type => Integer, :collection => true

end
```

In the similar way how can I define a two dimensional array using Domain model?

Comment: This gem doesn't have any usage example in the readme. Is your existing code working?

Comment: The validation process is extremely simple and thus not flexible to this extent. The process for collections is simply loop the `values` and check that they are a (`is_a?`) type. You could hack this functionality but it would be very case specific and I am unsure of our exact intentions. If you specify the desired valid input for numbers I might be able to assist in a **NOT RECOMMENDED** fashion

Comment: @maxpleaner yes my existing code is working.

Comment: To declare a two-dimensional array in Java, the syntax is as below
int[][] matrix = new int[2][3]

The input of numbers: 
   '1  2  3
    4 5  6'

Similar to the above, I want to know how I can do that in ruby using domain models?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found a solution to your question in `domain_model`.

When you include the `DomainModel` Module into your class it adds a class method called [`validate`](https://github.com/rafer/domain_model/blob/master/lib/domain_model.rb#L93). This method allows you to specify custom validation in the context of the instance so to validate that an Array contains only numbers at any depth this would be you code:

```
require 'domain_model'

class Sample
 include DomainModel


 field :numbers, :collection => true
 validate :numbers do |n|
   n.add("must contain only numbers") if self.numbers.flatten.any? {|value| !value.is_a?(Integer)}
 end
end
```

To validate that it contains only numbers in a 2 dimensional Array then

```
require 'domain_model'

class Sample
 include DomainModel


 field :numbers, :collection => true
 validate :numbers do |n|
   n.add("must contain only numbers") if self.numbers.flatten(1).any? {|value| !value.is_a?(Integer)}
 end
end
```

Comment: could you please share a working test code on how to populate this field?

Comment: You mean something as simple as `Sample.new(numbers:[[1,2,3],[4,5]])`